# regex problem in finding values separated by comma but not the last one in a string in python3

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```
>>> l
'sajo,asjoad,adjai'
>>> lp = re.findall(r'.+?,',l);lp
['sajo,', 'asjoad,']
```

Here I want the result with the last `adjai`. But the previous pattern isn't giving me the expexted result. Please help me.

Comment: You can simply use ```string.split(",")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, use a normal string split method here, the regex is not necessary if it is not required.

However, here is an explanation and a solution.

The `.+?,` expression matches any one or more characters as few as possible up to and including a comma. The comma is obligatory. That is why you have no match.

You can amend the expression to match **either `,` or the end of string** with `.+?(?:,|$)`:

```py
re.findall(r'.+?(?:,|$)',l)
```

With regex, use `[^,]+` to match any one or more characters other than a comma:

```
import re
l = 'sajo,asjoad,adjai'
print(re.findall(r'[^,]+',l))
```

[Result](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAnVewFWLj4uxLjCZNwAiplBQWX1/v@jcfaZtZebvo9Jod@93DoCpIowolpFSpgOta2gya17u0RMxB4bjwXAA5RrMf): `['sajo', 'asjoad', 'adjai']`

Comment: That's the regex way. However, the split function worked properly. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Using `string.split(",")` is an easy way to get a list of strings separated at commas.